# Is there a way to to use each value of an array as a function parameter and then store each result in another array or object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, asynchronous

so i have a function that returns array of matchIds. And i have a function that returns object of data from the macth based on the matchID

```
async function getMatchData(matchId){
    const response = await fetch(`https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/${matchId}?api_key=`+key);
    var data = await response.json();
    let matchData= {
        teams: data.info.teams.map(element => team = { teamid: element.teamId, win: element.win }),
        players: data.info.participants.map(element => obj = { team: element.teamId, champ: element.championName, champIcon: element.championName + '_0.jpg', summoner: element.summonerName, level: element.champLevel, build: { item1: element.item1, item2: element.item2, item3: element.item3, item4: element.item4, item5: element.item5, item6: element.item6, item0: element.item0 }, kills: element.kills, deaths: element.deaths, assists: element.assists, kda: (element.kills + element.assists) / element.deaths, cs: element.totalMinionsKilled + element.neutralMinionsKilled, victory: element.win })
    }
   return matchData
```

now i want to use each matchId from the matchIds array as a parameter in the getMatchData function and put each response in an array or object

i tried to run thru the array with map but it returns [
Promise {  }, Promise {  },
...
]
and says: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'teams')

```
let matchHistoryData= matches.map(element=>getMatchData(element))
     console.log(matchHistoryData);
```

matches being the array of matchIds

Comment: If you get that error, then `matches` is not what you think it is. Can you add a sample initialisation of `matches` that produces the problem? A wild guess: did you get `matches` from another request/response action? Are you sure it is not a promise object instead of an array of ids?

Comment: If it says `map` is not a function, then `matches` is definitely not an array, or may be it is not initialised yet.

Where did `matches` come from? Can you share more code to debug the issue?

Comment: @ArnoldParge it tuned out my api key had ran out  i updated it now but there is still a problem this is the response im given [Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },...] and the error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'teams') and where should i post more code in the comment section or edit the main post

Comment: @trincot as i said in the upper comment it turned out my api key was outdated however after updating it there is still an issue

Comment: So better update your question with the new information and new question, as it is one vote from getting closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question changed, so here is the answer to the updated question:

As `getMatchesData` is an `async` function, it is guaranteed to return a promise object. By consequence, the `.map()` call is bound to return an array of promises.

As these promises will only resolve in some future -- when these `await`-ed promises resolve, and `matchData` assignments get executed -- you'll need to listen in with asynchronous code to be executed when they do. You can use `Promise.all` for this:

```
Promise.all(matches.map(element=>getMatchData(element)))
       .then(matchHistoryData => {
           console.log(matchHistoryData);
       });
```

Note that any other code that needs `matchHistoryData` will need to run inside that `then` callback, or else be called from there (or be chained in yet another `then` callback,...).

#### Addendum

In comments you have presented code that wraps the code in a `logData` function. This doesn't take away the fact that the response data is only available in the future, so `logData` **cannot possibly** return that future data now. You have to stick with the asynchronous way of programming, and have your code executed in the future, when the promise resolves:

```
async function logData(sum){
    let name = sum;
    let puuid = await getPUUID(name);
    let matches = await getMatchIds(puuid);
    return Promise.all(matches.map(element => getMatchData(element)));
}

logData('ΤhePrideStalker').then(matchHistoryData => {
    console.log(matchHistoryData);
    /*
    All code that needs the values in matchHistoryData should
    be placed within this callback -- not outside of it.
    
    ...your code comes here...
    */
});

/* No code comes here that needs the results, because the results are not there yet */
```

Comment: im not sure if i dont understand how to use it or it doesnt work hers what i do
```async function logData(sum){
    let name=sum;
    console.log(name)
    let puuid= await getPUUID(name);
     console.log(puuid);
    let matches=await getMatchIds(puuid);
     console.log(matches);
    Promise.all(matches.map(element=>getMatchData(element)))
     .then(matchHistoryData => {
         console.log(matchHistoryData);
     });  
     
}
logData('ΤhePrideStalker')```
it doesnt return any `matchHistoryData` and error says:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'teams')

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, code that needs the results **must** be placed in the `then` callback or must be called from there. You cannot expect `logData` to return the data that will only be available in the future (later!). That is the whole principle of asynchronous execution. If you want `logData` can return the *promise* for the values, but then you must `return Promise.all(...` etc without its `then` call. Then `then` call must then happen on `logData(..).then`. You see? You need an asynchronous callback...

Comment: im really trying but i just dont get it.

Comment: You cannot expect to have a value *now* that is only available in the *future*. The `then` callback executes in that future, so all code that needs that future result, needs to be placed there, not outside that `then` callback. If you order a pizza online and press the final "Order" button, you cannot expect to see the pizza to be there on your plate immediately. There will be an event upon which you can react: that is the doorbell of the deliveryperson. In JavaScript that is the `then` callback.

Comment: is it suposed to be `async function logData(sum){...}` cuz if i do just `async logData(sum){...}` it gives error  and even if i try running it like  `async function logData(sum){...}` there is still the same problem it doesnt log `matchHistoryData`  and error says:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'teams')

Comment: Yes, I answered the original question about the array of promises, and you had added this error message to your question. This error message is trivial. It means that `data.info` is undefined. Of course that means you have to debug and explain why you expected there to be that `info` property, when it is not there. Debugging means here that you add a breakpoint and inspect the `data` variable.